# Problema com botoes quando clicado no AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

Tenho um app móvel com o seguinte problema: tenho uma lista de utilizadores que cada um tem um botão "seguir", que quando clicado terá de mudar para não seguir.

Retorno do PHP `true` ou `false` para saber se o utilizador que está logado no momento já está a seguir ou não o utilizador. O que acontece é que quando clico ele insere o seguidor bem, mas quando actualizo a página vou para por "não seguir", mas ele volta a inserir o seguidor em vez de o remover. Não sei qual o problema.

**Controller**

```
.controller('ListaSeguidoresUser', function($scope, $http, sessionService) {
    $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_seguidores_user.php?user_slug="+sessionService.get('user_slug')+"&user_id="+sessionService.get('user_id')).success(function (data) {
        angular.forEach(data, function(c) {
            $scope.seguidores_user = data;
            var hasLiked = c.hasLiked;
            $scope.seguir= function (id){
                if (!hasLiked) {
                    hasLiked = false;
                    c.seguir_user = "Não Seguir";
                    c.botao_seguir = "seguir_user_click";

                    $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_seguir_user.php?follower="+sessionService.get('user_id')+"&followed="+id).success(function (data) {
                        $scope.seguir_user = data;
                    });

                } else {
                    hasLiked = true;
                    c.seguir_user = "Seguir";
                    c.botao_seguir = "seguir_user_class";

                    $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_remover_seguir_user.php?follower="+sessionService.get('user_id')+"&followed="+id).success(function (data) {
                        $scope.nao_seguir_user = data;
                    });
                }     
            }
        });
    });
})
```

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="ListaSeguidoresUser">
         <div class="row" ng-repeat="seguidores in seguidores_user">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="list">
                    <a style="border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-top-left-radius:10px;  border:none;" class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#">
                         <img style="border-radius: 10px;" src="{{seguidores.user_foto}}">
                         <span style="font-weight:700; font-size:14px; color: black;">{{seguidores.nome}}</span>
                         <p>Seguidores {{seguidores.seguidores}}</p>
                         <p>Opiniões {{seguidores.opinioes}}</p>
                    </a> 
                    <div style="background-color: white; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; margin:0px -1px 0px -1px; border-bottom-left-radius:10px;  height: 45px;"> 
                        <div style="padding:5px 10px 0px 10px;">
                            <div ng-init="seguir_user=seguidores.seguir_user" ng-click="seguir({{seguidores.id}})" class="seguir_user" ng-class="botao_seguir=seguidores.botao_seguir" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> {{seguir_user}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: César, a sua pergunta está muito confusa. Por favor, edite a sua pergunta e explique-se melhor.

Comment: Eu retorno do php true ou false para saber se o utilizador que esta logado no momento ja esta a seguir ou nao o utilizador so que quando clico faz seguir quando actualizo a pagina vou para fazer nao seguir e ele inves de o remover volta a inserir novamente deve ser o if que esta mal

Comment: Veja o seu controller, você tem todo o seu código dentro do forEach. A cada ciclo você volta a definir a sua variável "hasLiked", que irá ficar com o valor do último item do array "data", deve ser por isso que não funciona.

Comment: tirei fora mas agora quando clico nao faz nada

Comment: O que retorna o api_seguir_user.php ? Um objecto "user"?

Comment: nao retorna nada e um insert só

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se assim funciona:

**Controller:**

```
.controller('ListaSeguidoresUser', function($scope, $http, sessionService) {
    $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_seguidores_user.php?user_slug="+sessionService.get('user_slug')+"&user_id="+sessionService.get('user_id')).success(function (data) {

        $scope.seguidores_user = data;

        $scope.seguir = function (index){
            var id = $scope.seguidores_user[index]['id'];

            if ($scope.seguidores_user[index]['hasLiked']) {

                $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_remover_seguir_user.php?follower="+sessionService.get('user_id')+"&followed="+id).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.seguidores_user[index]['hasLiked'] = false;
                });

            } else {

                $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_seguir_user.php?follower="+sessionService.get('user_id')+"&followed="+id).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.seguidores_user[index]['hasLiked'] = true;
                });

            }     
        }    
    });
})
```

**View**:

```
<div ng-controller="ListaSeguidoresUser">
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="seguidor in seguidores_user">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="list">
            <a style="border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-top-left-radius:10px;  border:none;" class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#">
                 <img style="border-radius: 10px;" src="{{seguidor.user_foto}}">
                 <span style="font-weight:700; font-size:14px; color: black;">{{seguidor.nome}}</span>
                 <p>Seguidores {{seguidor.seguidores}}</p>
                 <p>Opiniões {{seguidor.opinioes}}</p>
            </a>
            <div style="background-color: white; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; margin:0px -1px 0px -1px; border-bottom-left-radius:10px;  height: 45px;"> 
                <div style="padding:5px 10px 0px 10px;">                    
                    <div ng-click="seguir($index)" class="seguir_user" ng-class="{'seguir_user_click':seguidor.hasLiked, 'seguir_user_class':!seguidor.hasLiked}" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                        <span ng-if="seguidor.hasLiked">Não Seguir</span>
                        <span ng-if="!seguidor.hasLiked">Seguir</span>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: aparece todos a vermelho sem o texto no botao e ao clicar nao faz nada

Comment: em relação ao texto no botão, faltava fechar corretamente o </span>, corrigi o código, estava "</spa>", faltava o "n" no fim. Veja se agora aparece o texto.

Comment: Agora aparece reparei nisso depois mas o botao ao clicar nao acontece nada e ficam todos com a class vermelha que e de nao seguir

Comment: o que retorna o "api_seguidores_user.php"? Dentro da resposta (o array "data") existe a propriedade "hasLiked"?

Comment: sim existe eu vou por na pergunta como esta o php

Comment: faz inspecionar elemento no google Chrome, clique em "console" e veja se ocorre algum erro ao clicar em um dos botões.

Comment: da isto `Error: id is not defined`

Comment: peço desculpas, me esqueci de atualizar o "id", alterei o controller, adicionei a variável "id". Veja se funciona.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31064/discussion-between-cesar-sousa-and-filipe-moraes).

Comment: Funciona bem ja so as class e que estao ao contrario

Comment: Basta então trocar o "ng-if" na view, atualizei o HTML, veja se ficou bem agora.

Comment: sim ja troquei e funciona certinho e mesmo isto

Comment: Ótimo, fico feliz em ajuda-lo!

Comment: Muito obrigado ajudou e muito mesmo

Comment: Tente entender o que foi feito, assim no futuro será mais fácil implementar novas soluções. :)

Comment: e isso que vou fazer :)